# How to add multiple subnets of multiple vnets to azure servicebus firewall dynamically using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

How to add multiple subnets of multiple VNETS to azure ServiceBus firewall dynamically using terraform?

Below is the terraform code. VNETs and subnets is available in the locals section of tf code.

So I have three VNETs (vnet1, vnet2, and vnet3) in azure and each VNET has multiple subnets.

```
locals {
 virtual_network_name1 = "vnet1"
 virtual_network_name2 = "vnet2"
 virtual_network_name3 = "vnet3"
 subnets = {
   sub1 : {
     subnet1 = "vnet1-subnet1",
     subnet2 = "vnet1-subnet2",
     subnet3 = "vnet1-subnet3"
   },
   sub2: {
     subnet1 = "vnet2-subnet1",
     subnet2 = "vnet2-subnet2",
     subnet3 = "vnet2-subnet3"
   }
sub3: {
     subnet1 = "vnet3-subnet1",
     subnet2 = "vnet3-subnet2",
     subnet3 = "vnet3-subnet3"
   }
 
}
}

data "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
 name                 = local.virtual_network_name
 resource_group_name  = "westy"
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "subnets" {
 for_each             = local.subnets
 name                 = each.value
 resource_group_name  = "westy"
 virtual_network_name = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name

}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_servicebus_namespace" "example" {
  name                = "example-sb-namespace"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku                 = "Premium"

  capacity = 1
}


resource "azurerm_servicebus_namespace_network_rule_set" "example" {
  namespace_name      = azurerm_servicebus_namespace.example.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  default_action = "Deny"

  trusted_services_allowed = true

  network_rules {
    subnet_id                            = data.azurerm_subnet.subnets
    ignore_missing_vnet_service_endpoint = false
  }


  ip_rules = ["125.123.142.174"]
 
 
}
```

Actually, these are existing VNETs and subnets were already created

I want to iterate over those vnets like with vnet1 iterate the first group of subnets, with vnet2 iterate the second group subnets and same with vnet3. This is how respective subnets are associated with those vnets and add them inside the network block of "azurerm_servicebus_namespace_network_rule_set" resource dynamically using terraform?

Is it possible to achieve?

Comment: You are not using your local variables at all. How exactly are you creating your vnets `virtual_network_name1` and others? How do this relates to your `subnets`?

Comment: I have forgotten to add that those vnets and subnets were already created and  I want to use datasource terraform resource to add them inside network rule set of servicebus. How do I achieve it?

Comment: Glad to be of help @devops-admin :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code for your requirement:

```
provider "azurerm"{
  features{}
}
locals {
 vnet_list = {    
  "vnet1" = [{"subnet_name"=[
                    "subnet1",
                    "subnet2",
                    "subnet3"
  ]
  }],
  "vnet2" = [{"subnet_name"=[
                    "subnet1",
                    "subnet2",
                    "subnet3"
  ]
                 }], 
  "vnet3" = [{"subnet_name"=[
                    "subnet1",
                    "subnet2",
                    "subnet3"
                  ]
  }]
}
vnet = merge([
    for vnet_name, vnet in local.vnet_list : {
      for subnet in vnet[0].subnet_name :
          "${vnet_name}-${subnet}" => {
            name               = vnet_name
            subnet_name  =  subnet
          }
    }
  ]...)
}
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "myresourcegroup"
}

resource "azurerm_servicebus_namespace" "example" {
  name                = "ansuman-sb-namespace"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku                 = "Premium"

  capacity = 1
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "example"{
  for_each = local.vnet
  name=each.value.subnet_name
  virtual_network_name=each.value.name
  resource_group_name=data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_servicebus_namespace_network_rule_set" "example" {
  namespace_name      = azurerm_servicebus_namespace.example.name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  default_action = "Deny"
  trusted_services_allowed = true

  dynamic "network_rules" {
    for_each=data.azurerm_subnet.example
    content{
    subnet_id                            = network_rules.value["id"]
    ignore_missing_vnet_service_endpoint = false
  }
  }
  ip_rules = ["125.123.142.174"]
}
```

**Output:**

**All the 9 Subnets have been added in the network rule:**

[image]

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]